# Extracting JSON data into Javascript object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Following are my JSON data :

```
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "retailername": "Zop Now",
                "value": 475
            },
            {
                "retailername": "Snap Deal",
                "value": 265
            },
            {
                "retailername": "Natures Basket",
                "value": 86
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want is:

```
[
    {
        "retailername": "Zop Now",
        "value": 475
    },
    {
        "retailername": "Snap Deal",
        "value": 265
    },
    {
        "retailername": "Natures Basket",
        "value": 86
    }
]
```

That much of part from above data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd love to see your own efforts first.

Comment: First thanx for your good advise. I have try. I have also try following two answers but it's show me undefined error.

Comment: You should post the code you're using. Even if you're getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```js
var data = [{"items":[{"retailername":"Zop Now","value":475},{"retailername":"Snap Deal","value":265},{"retailername":"Natures Basket","value":86}]}]

var items = data[0]["items"];

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Hi Vijay.. It's give me undefined output.

Comment: @Tanisha - please `console.log(data)` first. If its gives you correct output then above code should work. Please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what you expect :

```
var jsonbase = [{
  "items": [{
    "retailername": "Zop Now",
    "value": 475
  }, {
    "retailername": "Snap Deal",
    "value": 265
  }, {
    "retailername": "Natures Basket",
    "value": 86
  }]
}];



var json = jsonbase[0].items;

console.log(json);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/scuozurn/

Comment: Hi Quentin.. It's give me undefined output.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```js
let data, arr;
    data = [{"items":[{"retailername":"Zop Now","value":475},{"retailername":"Snap Deal","value":265},{"retailername":"Natures Basket","value":86}]}];
    arr = [];
    for(let i =0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty('items') && data[i].items instanceof Array){
            arr.push(data[i].items);
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = [{
  "items": [{
    "retailername": "Zop Now",
    "value": 475
  }, {
    "retailername": "Snap Deal",
    "value": 265
  }, {
    "retailername": "Natures Basket",
    "value": 86
  }]
}];



var getJson = obj[0]['items']; //or

var get_Json = obj[0].items;

console.log(getJson) // or ;
   console.log(get_Json);
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/36e91rr4/1/

Comment: above code returns - [Object { retailername="Zop Now",  value=475}, Object { retailername="Snap Deal",  value=265}, Object { retailername="Natures Basket",  value=86}]

Comment: try it like this console.log(getJson) // or ;
   console.log(get_Json);

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting errors, probably you do not have a valid javascript object, and it might be in string format.

try

```
var obj = JSON.parse(your_original_object);
```

and Then,

```
var get_Json = obj[0].items;
```

should give you the object you are looking for.